# Vba code to delete all slides with a blank layout powerpoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Looking for an example vba code that deletes all slides with a blank layout.

I am trying to create a catalog using a UserForm. The user selects which products they want to look at and the code deletes the slides of the products they don't want to look at.

The problem is that if I delete the array of slides specific to a product, it changes the total number of slides and then the other slide number arrays no longer contain the slides specific to the other products.

I was thinking I would add blank slides in place of the undesired slides and then delete all of the blank slides at the end.

I am open to other ideas and suggestions. Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: Always delete slides backwards - from the last one to first one.

Comment: Thank you, what a simple fix!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you're working with arrays of SlideNumber or SlideIndex.
Never bother with SlideNumber for various reasons.
And in this case, SlideIndex will change after you delete slides.

Instead, either work with arrays of Slide objects or instead of SlideIndex, use an array of SlideId ... SlideIds are assigned when the slide is created and never change.

Example of how to find a slide from its SlideID, in this case, 258 arbitrarily:

```
Dim oSl As Slide
Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(258)
MsgBox oSl.SlideIndex
```